# Liquibase azure and database sequences

Tags: sql-server, azure, liquibase

During my work with porting our app to Azure I bumped on an interesting issue - liquibase does not support create sequence statement for sql server on azure. Anybody knows why?

I found even a post on liquibase forum, but noone cared to respond:
http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/createsequence-is-not-supported-on-azure-ms-sql

Author of this post found this snippet of code in MSSQLDatabase class:

```
@Override
    public boolean supportsSequences() {
        try {
            if (isAzureDb()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.getDatabaseMajorVersion() >= 11) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: hey did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes I implemented my own version of liquibase driver.

Comment: Can I know the solution if you don't mind?

Comment: Just download liquibase jar (it is open source) and modify supportsSequences function to return true.

Comment: yes did that but still, it didn't work for me. let me try again if it helps me.Thanks